# unzip many files with different passwords and compression formats with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, compression, zip

I have this bash script to unzip files with different passwords. But it decompresses indefinitely and damages the decompressed files

```
PASS="passfoo passbar passfoobar"
LIST=$(ls -1 *.{zip,7z,7z.001,rar})
for password in $PASS; do
  OIFS="$IFS"
  IFS=$'\n'
  for i in $LIST
  do
      echo "$password"
      7z x -y -p"$password" "$i" -aoa
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     continue
    fi
   done
   IFS="$OIFS"
  done
```

To temporarily fix it I have had to create a loop for each password.

What I want is that when the script matches a password, the script won't test the others, and if there is no match with any password that tries to decompress it normally (if it does not have a password) or that shows an error (if the file has a password but it is not in the variable) without stopping to decompress the other files. Thk

PD: Keep in mind that files to decompress sometimes come with names with space and other non-ASCII characters, or are files compressed by parts

Comment: Side note: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the `continue` is the correct action inside the inner loop but I have adjusted your code to this.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

passw=(
  passfoo
  passbar
  passfoobar
  banana
  chocolate
  whiskey
  vodka
  icecream
)

for f in *.@(zip|7z|7z.001|rar); do
  for p in "${passw[@]}"; do
    if 7z x -y -p"$p" "$f" -aoa; then
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

- the `shopt -s` enables the shell options that are not enabled by default, `shopt -u` to disable the options.
- `extglob` a feature that let's you do the `*.@(zip|7z|rar)` to match different file extensions. which expands to `*.zip` `*.7z` and `*.rar` and expands to all the files in the directory that ends in that particular extension (if there are files) not sure about the order though.
- `nullglob` If there are no files ending in the pattern `*.@(zip|7z|rar)` nothing will be evaluated so it will be empty, if not enabled the glob will expand to a *literal* `*.rar` or `*.7z` or `*.zip` which will cause an error to your script.

Edit:  As per the OP's @ajcg , I have change the continue to break so it works as expected.

Comment: I don't use `7z` so I can't really say anything about that, I just adjusted your script is all.

Comment: Please modify the loop and change "continue" to "break". That's how it works. To select your answer as correct. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well at least we both learn something from this...

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of "shopt -s extglob nullglob"? Thank you

Comment: I have added an explanation, see the section of the bash manual about those things.