# extract .rar multiparts with bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, zip, 7-zip

i run [this script](https://superuser.com/a/1547121/886205) but this have a problem with extract rar multiparts

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

passw=(
  passfoo
  passbar
  passfoobar
  banana
  chocolate
  whiskey
  vodka
  icecream
)

for f in *.@(rar|zip|zip.001|7z|7z.001); do
  for p in "${passw[@]}"; do
    if 7z x -y -p"$p" "$f" -aoa; then
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

With `.zip` or `.7z` it decompresses the multiparts well, because the extension of the multiparts are equal (for `.7z` = `7z.001`, `7z.002`, etc. For `.zip` = `zip.001`, `zip.002`, etc). The problem is that if I add this to the script:

```
*.@(rar|part1.rar|zip|zip.001|7z|7z.001)
```

It fails because `*.partX.rar` and `.rar` both end in **.rar** and the loop unzips the same thing over and over again or fails in `.part2.rar` onwards if the file has password

**Failed attempts to fix the problem:**

1. To exclude any file from `.part2.rar` (example: `*.part{2..99}.rar`)
2. With the [switch "-x"](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/exclude.htm)

I appreciate help completing the loop and integrating decompression of multipart files in `.rar` format

Comment: You just want to skip the `part[0-9].rar` in the loop maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do in the outer loop may be to check if `$f` qualifies to be skipped.

In Bash you can do this with `[[`, using either pattern matching (with `=`, `==` or `!=`) or a regex (with `=~`). The latter option is more powerful. It your case this should work:

```
for f in *.@(rar|zip|zip.001|7z|7z.001); do
  [[ ( "$f" =~ \.part[[:digit:]]+\.rar$ ) && ! ( "$f" =~ \.part0*1\.rar$ ) ]] && continue
  for p …
```

The expressions I used consist of these parts:

- `\.` – matches a literal dot
- `part`, `rar`, `1` – these match `part`, `rar` and `1` literally, respectively
- `[[:digit:]]+` – matches one or more digits (as defined by the current locale)
- `0*` – matches zero or more `0` characters
- `$` – matches the end of string being tested

`!` negates.

The logic is like this: if the filename ends with `.part<digit(s)>.rar` and it doesn't end with `.part1.rar` (or `.part01.rar`, or `.part001.rar` etc.) then resume the next iteration (i.e. take the next `f` and start over).

---

If I were you, I would add `nocaseglob` to the `shopt -s …` line, to match names like `FOO.RAR` with your pattern (`*.@(rar|zip|zip.001|7z|7z.001)`). My tests indicate it's enough to make my solution (`=~`) work with them as well (no need to additionaly enable `nocasematch`).

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob nocaseglob
```